# Gutenberg Templates: Core Block Attributes

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-admin, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

The Gutenberg Handbook currently has a short entry for creating whole templates of blocks used e.g. for Custom Post Types or the like.

https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/templates/

It seems to be missing a comprehensive overview of the core/-Blocks though. Especially the available attributes are interesting here. Is there a reference-entry I am just missing?

To elaborate:

By playing around, I found out a few things. E.g. preformatted blocks do take the formatting of a php file like line breaks, indends and tabs, which makes them a bit sensitive..

```
array( 'core/preformatted', array(
                            'content' => 'Grundlegende Fakten:

Operator: Max Mustermann
Wo: City, Country
Wer: 99999 Kinder
Wieviel: 99999 Angestellte',
                            ) ),
```

This does translate into: 
(note that every tab or indent before later lines would have been taken over as well)

[image: Screenshot]

So - what other possibilities do i have to modify the 'content' and 'placeholder' attributes? Can I make use of the fact that they are arrays and insert selectors or other html like .. This does NOT work:

```
array( 'core/preformatted', array(
    'content' => array('selector' => 'h1', 'content' => 'Does this do anything?'),
) ),
```

..But this DOES:

```
array( 'core/preformatted', array(
    'content' => array('Does', 'this', 'do', 'anything?'),
) ),
```

And where can I find a comprehensive list of first order attributes, since e.g it's not always clear whether a core/block will take a 'text'-string or a 'content'-array and so on..

Answer (score 3):

To partly answer my own question:

As mentioned in [this git issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/4340) you can use

```
console.log(wp.blocks.getBlockTypes());
```

in the browser console after all the Gutenberg magic loaded (e.g. in the editor window of a post) to show all currently registered blocks, inluding their attributes.

Definitely a helpful tool!

Answer (score 0):

Another Info-Source:

[The Git-Project of Gutenberg holds all core blocks](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-library/src) and their properties can be accessed by

***Name-of-Block*/index.js**

Then find: **const blockAttributes =**

Comment: Attributes are now located in src / _block-name_ / block.json